# Can't push to git via Android studio?

Tags: android, git, git-push

I cloned a Repository from Github via Android Studio. I made some changes to the code, then committed & pushed without a problem. Today, I made some changes to the code. I committed them but when I tried to push them it says

> Can't push, because no remotes are defined

[image]
Thanks for your help..

Comment: I have the same issue. The remote has clearly been set up and I can push with Git extensions without any problem, but I see this screen in Android studio.

Answer (score 10):

Apparently there's no way to do it from the IDE, some bug must have deleted your remote.  If you open up the config file in your .git directory within your project folder, goto the bottom and insert:

```
[remote "origin"]
url = https://github.com/YOURPROFILE/YOURREPO.git
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, it is late to answer, but I got related problem yesterday in IDEA.
I have separate repository for each module and when I initially checkout them into local repository all remotes were called **origin**. Yesterday I changed remotes for some modules but not by replacing - by adding **new_remote** and removing **origin**. So I got smth like that:

```
module_1 -> {new_remote/master}
module_2 -> {origin/master}
module_3 -> {origin/master}
...
module_n -> {new_remote/master}
```

From that moment I received error **Can't push, because no remotes are defined** every time I tried to push. In git bash all worked fine, but not in IDEA. I spent whole day and at evening I tried last solution and it worked - **I changed all local repositories to have identically named remotes**. In my case, I renamed **origin** for modules to **new_remote**.
As I understant you can have smth like this:

```
module_1 -> {origin->[master, test], staging->[master]}
module_2 -> {origin->[master], staging->[master]}
module_3 -> {origin->[master, test]}
```

But from Intellij native plugins in this case you will be able to push only to {origin->[master]}, because only this remote/branch pair is common to all registered in this project repositories.

ALso, it seems that this limitation wil  be fixed in later versions. - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-81620