# Can't push to bitbucket because no remotes are defined

Tags: android, git, bitbucket

I cannot push my project to Bitbucket via Android Studio because no remotes are defined. I used this Stackoverflow question as a source but it didn't help:

"[Can't push to git via Android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22614715/cant-push-to-git-via-android-studio)"

*Note: The remote and/or origin may have been deleted accidentaly. Also, two repositories or roots may have been created from this one project. (I know, I know...)

I have only just started using git and bitbucket and I hope I didn't ruin my project. The commit works fine until the very end where the git screen shows up blank and says on the bottom "...no remotes are defined". Is there a quick fix or maybe it's possible to create another new repository for my project?

Here is the config.git file of my project:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://xxxxxx@bitbucket.org/xxxxxx/yyyyyy.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Please let me know if you notice any error in this config file or if there is another config file I should be looking at...

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

In `Git Bash` I added another remote and called `git remove remote origin`. Then I called `git push` on the new remote and it worked. However, this only works on `Git Bash`. On Android Studio, it still says no remotes are defined... I wonder if I am supposed to configure something on Android Studio?

**UPDATE2**

Now I get this strange error:

```
Error:error: pathspec 'appname/src/main/res/drawable/back.png' did not match any file(s) known to git.
 during executing git commit --only -F C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\git-commit-msg-5810111251677391833.txt --
```

Answer (score -1):

Solution 1:

Go to Git bash. Cd to your project folder and add remotes again by using following commands

> git remote add origin "Paste your bitbucket link here"

eg - git remote add origin https://kanand90@bitbucket.org/kanand90/algorithms.git

The check if you have set your remote correctly by typing

> git remote -v

This should show you your push and pull remotes. I think this should solve the problem.

Solution 2:

Simply make a copy of your project(copy and paste) in some other location. Delete the .git physically from the new copy. Import the new copy into android studio again. Go to version control System(VCS)->Import into Version Control->Share project on github or bitbucket(whichever you have set up). Then enter master password and new repository name. Then your setup is complete.

Comment: "git remote add origin "Paste your bitbucket link here". I did that and got the result: "fatal: remote origin already exists". Then when I did git remove -v I got two results: origin https...project.git(fetch) and origin https...project.git(push)

Comment: Try `git remote set-url origin <your-bitbucket-url>` instead.

Comment: Unfortunately none of it seems to be working. How do I delete git physically from a new copy? Is it command line code in `Git Bash` or just locate git files and press delete?

Comment: perhaps check out my updates above? maybe it's an issue with Android Studio?

Comment: How do you delete git physcially from the new copy? How many git files are there?

Comment: Go in folder and delete the .git folder. If its not visible then do ls -all or equivalent windows cmd command and it will be visible